# What voltage range will I need for my multiplexers?

Tags: voltage, multiplexer, negative-voltage

I'm trying to make a Fuzz guitar pedal effect (for a guitarist in the bands I play in), and I found this one:

[The Fuzz of 1000 Faces](https://www.instructables.com/id/The-Fuzz-of-1000-Faces/)

Made by Randy Randofo.

Below is the circuit from that site:

[image]

I made already a (big) breadboard setup to mimic the routing using multiplexers (CD4051's, CD4052's and 74HC595's shift registers for controlling including a STM32F103), using LEDs. This works fine.

For the CD4051's and CD4052's I use now for VCC 5 V, and I connect VEE (negative) to ground, which works perfectly for LEDS, as they are switched on with 5V and switched off with 0V, thus no negative voltages.

However, I realized I'm using audio, actually from a guitar pickup, which is +/- some volts. Also as can be seen in the circuit, the power voltage is 9 V.

I am wondering now, what voltage I should use for the VCC and VEE for the multiplexers (CD4051's/CD4052's). If I take the most worst case route, which is 9V -> 10K resistor -> C2 -> 100K Pot -> OUT (looking at the small circuit in the upper right corner, copied below), than when the 100K pot is set to 100 K, the voltage at C2 (and thus Q2 etc), will be close to 9 V, so I expect I need -9 V to +9 V to my multiplexers.

[image]

This also is kind of shown in the Fuzz faze description of [ElectroSmash Fuzz Face](https://www.electrosmash.com/fuzz-face), which shows -8.7 Volts (although resistor values are different and inverted because a germanium AC128 uses negative voltage). See screenshot below.

[image]

So can someone confirm (possibly with a bit of explanation), if I should use for my multiplexers VCC +9 V and VEE -9 V?

Comment: Whatever battery you are using, connect Vcc and Vee to the battery positive and negative nodes. Also, is there that much of a fuzz effect difference when using different NPN silicon transistors? An AC128 fuzz box is awesome if you can get 'em. It's got a proper old skool prog rock sound.

Comment: @Andyaka I'm not using a battery, but the guitarist has an isolated multi-channel 9V power supply. I tried some time ago (before Corona) several different transistors and he could hear a difference. I have AC128's (from China), but not tested those yet. Although I cannot use the AC128's in my NPN circuit (at least I don't know how).

Comment: I don't think that should make a difference. What about AC127s?

Comment: You mean using different transistors? hmm wondering why that Fuzz of 1000 faces is made that way. The project also got a bit out of hand, meaning I thought it would be not that difficult, but it's getting huge (at least for me)... At least I learn a lot about multiplexers/shift registers.

Comment: I didn't try AC127's (don't have them neither). (after editing your comment it was clear you meant transistors).

Comment: It shouldn't make a difference where the power comes from providing it doesn't exceed the maximum for the CD4051/2 - that's what I meant.

Comment: I'd also be tempted to use the [ADG1604](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADG1604.pdf) and, I believe ADI make an 8:1 version....1606

Comment: @Andyaka So I can use 9V for all multiplexers's VCC and GND for multiplexer's VEE... That makes it easier. Than I only need level shifters for the channel selectors (as the STM32 works with 3.3V)

Comment: If you used the Analog Device parts I don't think they need level shifters.

Comment: @Andyaka good to know these exist, but they are quite expensive, and TSSOP (I need to handsolder them). And another reason is that I already have all the DIP-version multiplexers for testing and the SOP/SOIC version for the PCB. I know that's not a good reason, but this is 'just' a hobby project.

Comment: @Andyaka yes I just checked the data sheet, and they should be able to be switched with 3.3V (need 2V for a HIGH signal), and the analog signals can be 10 V.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106504/discussion-between-michel-keijzers-and-andy-aka).